# How can I change context by appending environment?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, tomcat6

I have multiple running application on same tomcat server 
**URL:**

```
www.myserver.com/application1-name.
www.myserver.com/application2-name.
www.myserver.com/application3-name.
```

Now I need change my context by adding environment as mentioned below

```
www.myserver.com/env1/application1-name.
www.myserver.com/env1/application2-name.
www.myserver.com/env1/application3-name.
```

Can anybody please tell me how can I add **/env1** in my context path either through JSF or Tomcat ???

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to your server.xml file in tomcat ..

```
<Host>
          .
          .
          .
<Context docBase="application1-name" path="/env1" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>            
<Context docBase="application2-name" path="/env1" debug="0" reloadable="true"/> 
<Context docBase="application3-name" path="/env1" debug="0" reloadable="true"/> 
</Host>
</Engine>
</Service>
</Server>
```